# Bivariate normal distribution problem

Tags: probability, statistics

Let X be the heigh of the father and Y the height of the son. The two  random variables distributed with bivariate normal distribution, as demonstrated by Pearson in 1900. If E [X] = 68 inches and E [Y] = 69 inches, σx=σy = 2 and p = 0.5 :
Find if the son of a father who has a height of 80 inches, is taller than his father.

My solution:

Calculate: X|(Y=80)~Ν (  ,  ) (by using this formula http://prntscr.com/33si9s)
Compare the mean that i will find above with 80 that is the height of the son.

I am not sure that this is the right solution.Any ideas? (Hints/Answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems to be asking you for the probability that the son with a father of height 80 inches is taller than that father. The answer is
$$
\int_{80}^\infty f(x|Y=80)dx
$$
where $f(x|Y=y)$ is the PDF of the normal distribution on the RHS below:
$$
X|(Y=y)\sim N\left(\mu_x+\frac{\sigma_x}{\sigma_y}\rho(y-\mu_y),(1-\rho^2)\sigma_x^2\right).
$$